# What are the benefits of using Lightning Web Components with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, node.js

I understand that LWCs are based on new JS standards and features and so the heavyweight Aura framework is no longer needed.  But if I'm building something on Node.js, is there a reason to use LWCs besides getting access to Salesforce base components and the Lightning Design System?  If I'm building an app with a non-salesforce look and feel can I use any UI library I choose (Angular, JQuery, etc) or is there some tangible benefit with the LWC library.

I'm coming at this project from a Java and Salesforce developer background rather than a Javascript coder so I'm concerned I might be misunderstanding where Javascript ends and LWCs begin and what would be lost by skipping the LWC framework altogether.

Any directional guidance and clarification will be appreciated.

Comment: i'd suggest you lookup [web components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) and read on the subject. lwc is just the Salesforce proprietary name for using it within salesforce. After all, LWC is Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That is indeed the heart of my question.  Does Lightning add anything of value to Javascript web components beyond a set of UI components?

Comment: Is the solution you're developing going to live in SFDC? Or are you talking about the open-source lwc? you should ask your question in a narrower way, it is way too vague as it is.

Comment: It's not going to be in Salesforce.  It will run in Node but will connect to Salesforce via both the regular REST api and the metadata api.  So it would be open source LWC.  but it occurs to me that open source LWC is just Javascript web components with a library of components pre-built.  And as I'm not convinced that the Salesforce look and feel is appropriate for my usecase, I think I'm just going to stay native and use very little, if any, of the LWC component library.  Although am I right in saying that the lwc framework is how dynamic values are put in the HTML pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LWC is minimalistic framework. It's super-small, leverages native browser technology when possible (some 90% of the LWC stack is browser tech), and faster than most other frameworks. LWC isn't bulky like jQuery, doesn't mix template and script like React and Angular, and isn't overly confusing to use relative to those frameworks. It's simple enough to be your "first" framework, but powerful enough to be the "last" framework you'll need for a while.

Also, the JavaScript you'll learn will be applicable to basically any other web framework you will use for the foreseeable future. If you learn React, by comparison, you'll find that almost nobody else does it that way, so you have to "unteach" yourself a bit. Because LWC is so close to the standards, it gives you a solid foundation for future projects.

I would say that starting from LWC and moving on to other frameworks (Angular, etc) would be a much easier task than the other way around. You'll also get the advantage of learning plain JavaScript, which is used in virtually every framework anyways.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  There's talk in my team of using Bootstrap to implement front end magic.  Do you have any thoughts on that?  I'm just getting started in javascript and, if possible, would like to not lean into inferior toolset as I have a limited amount of learning time I can invest!

Comment: @alanbrown Bootstrap still requires you to write HTML, and quite a bit of it, unless you go with something like smart-bootstrap, which is a web component wrapper for Bootstrap. Also, Bootstrap makes no provisions for unit testing, which may or may not be important to you. LWC takes very little time to learn itself, most of that time will be spent learning JavaScript, which if you don't already have, you'll need for Bootstrap anyways. I see no downsides to taking a trip through LWC to wherever you want to go.